# Why are checkboxes not reset by v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is what i have:

1. Template

   ```html
   <div
     v-for="(filter, index) in filtersList"
     :key="index"
     class="option-block"
   >
     <label
       v-for="value in filter.values"
       :key="value.id"
       class="option-block__container"
     >
       {{ value.title }}
       <input
         type="checkbox"
         v-model="filtersValues[filter.name]"
         :value="value.value"
       >
       <span class="option-block__checkmark"></span>
     </label>
   </div>
   ```
2. And the part of my vue code:

   ```js
   data() {
     return {
       filtersList: {},
       filtersValues: {}
     }
   },
   beforeMount() {
     this.loadInitData();
     this.initFilters();
   },
   methods: {
     loadInitData() {
       const data = JSON.parse(this.$el.getAttribute('data-data'));

       this.filtersList = data.filters;
     },
     initFilters() {
       for (let i in this.filtersList) {
         if (!this.filtersList.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
           continue;
         }
         this.filtersValues[this.filtersList[i].name] = [];
       }
     }
   }
   ```

It works, but when i call `initFilters()` method again (for reseting) checkboxes are still selected, and i don't know why.

Comment: Is `filtersList` an object or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did `filter.values` come from in line 2 of template?

Anyways vue would not be able to track the changes you are making (judging from the visible code)

There are some caveats to vue 2's reactivity. [Check here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for more info.

TLDR; you will need to declare anything you want to be made reactive in the component's data option upfront.

HTH

Comment: Oh, sorry, i missed that part. Updated the question. `filter` is item of the `filtersList`. `filtersList` is a object from php. Problem solved by`this.$set`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are assigning new, empty arrays to `filterValues` is [not reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

If you change your `initFilters` to assign an entire new value to `filterValues`, you don't need to worry about using `Vue.set()`. For example

```js
initFilters() {
  this.filtersValues = this.filtersList.reduce((vals, { name }) => ({
    ...vals,
    [ name ]: []
  }), {})
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/cjx09zwt/

Comment: Yes it works for me. Thanks. And it's better than `Vue.set()`?

Comment: I don't know if _better_ is the right word but `Vue.set()` always feels like a last resort to me